# SammysRentalPrice JOptionPane

Tags: java, string, joptionpane

- List item

I am in a Java class and I have been prompted to do a lab from the book.

> Sammy’s Seashore Supplies rents beach equipment such as kayaks, canoes, beach chairs, and umbrellas to tourists. Write a program that prompts the user for the number of minutes he rented a piece of sports equipment. Compute the rental cost as $40 per hour plus $1 per additional minute. (You might have surmised already that this rate has a logical flaw, but for now, calculate rates as described here. You can fix the problem after you read the chapter on decision making.) Display Sammy’s motto with the border that you created in the SammysMotto2 class in Chapter 1. Then display the hours, minutes, and total price. Save the file as SammysRentalPrice.jav

Now I am trying to do it with JOptionPane but I am not sure where to go from what I have.

```
package sammysrentalprice;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SammysRentalPrice
{

   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       final int RENT_PER_HOUR = 40;
       final int RENT_PER_ADDITIONAL_MINUTE = 1;
       final int MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR = 60;
        
        int minutesRented;
        int hoursRented;
        int additionalMinutes;
        int total;
        
        
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
               "SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n"
               + "SS                                                                        SS \n"
               + "SS    Sammy's makes it fun in the sun.      SS \n"
                + "SS                                                                        SS \n"
                       + "SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n");
        
       
    }
   
    
}

Example of what we should use (This was the lab before the one we are on)
 
package chap2.carlyseventprice;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Chap2CarlysEventPrice 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final int PRICE_PER_PERSON = 35;
        final int LARGE_EVENT = 50;
        
        String strNumOfGuests;
        int numOfGuests;
        int totalPrice;
                
        strNumOfGuests = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter the number of guests", "Guest Entry",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        numOfGuests = Integer.parseInt(strNumOfGuests);
        
        totalPrice = numOfGuests * PRICE_PER_PERSON; 
        
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
               "*****************************************************\n"
              + "* Carly's makes the food that makes it a party! *\n"
              + "*****************************************************");
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
               "Number Of Guests: " + numOfGuests
                + "\nPrice per Guest: " + PRICE_PER_PERSON
                +"\nTotal Price:      $" + totalPrice
                + "\nLarge event? " + (numOfGuests >= 50));
    }
```

Comment: You should probably add the "Swing" tag.

Comment: I'd like to know the name of the book you are using. Personally, I don't think it's a good idea to put `JOptionPane` in a console application. I don't think that is the intended use of `JOptionPane`. I think a console application should only use standard output and standard input. Why don't you simply make a GUI application?

Comment: We are using Joyce Farrell's Java Programming.9th edition. and it doesn't say to use JOption, my professor has shown us JOptionPane and I personally liked the way it works and he said we could use either.

Comment: And I might be mistaken, is JOptionPane not a GUI application? I am still a learning student just in my second week of class haha.

Comment: A `JOptionPane` is a GUI component that can be part of a GUI application. Refer to [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to change it to show a input dialog instead of a message dialog. This can be done by changing `showMessageDialog` to `showInputDialog`

Keep in mind that `showInputDialog` returns a string so you'll have to parse it to an int.

After that you can do the calculation.

The code should look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final int RENT_PER_HOUR = 40;
    final int RENT_PER_ADDITIONAL_MINUTE = 1;
    final int MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR = 60;
    
    int minutesRented;
    int hoursRented;
    int additionalMinutes;
    int total;
    
    String strNumberOfMinutes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Enter the number of minutes", "Number of Minutes",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
              "SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n"
            + "SS                                                                        SS \n"
            + "SS    Sammy's makes it fun in the sun.      SS \n"
            + "SS                                                                        SS \n"
            + "SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\n");
    
    minutesRented = Integer.parseInt(strNumberOfMinutes);
    
    hoursRented = minutesRented / MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR;
    additionalMinutes = minutesRented - (hoursRented*MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR);
    
    total = additionalMinutes*RENT_PER_ADDITIONAL_MINUTE + hoursRented*RENT_PER_HOUR;
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
              "Hours: "+hoursRented+"\n"
            + "Min: "+additionalMinutes+"\n"
            + "Total Cost: "+total);
}
```

Comment: When I ran that code it did not work, I am still a student and learning so I might have messed up. But we haven't been taught anything about Math.Floor(Float)

Comment: I added an example of the code we should be using, It was from our lab before this, i just do not know how to use it with the new problem.

Comment: Math.floor(float) takes a number and rounds it down. In this case, it makes it so you only have the hours left after dividing (numberOfMin / 60). Also, thanks for clarifying on the example. What you'll have to do is create a new "JOptionPane.showInputDialog" before you show the message dialog, since that's what they appear to do in the example. I'll try and update the code on my answer.

Comment: Also, could you explain the error you're getting when running the old code?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! is there a way to write this without math.floor(Float) We haven't been taught that yet and don't want to go too far ahead of the class haha.  and on that error I got, I am not sure what it said I do not have access to it anymore. bu ti believe it was because of (input) you had on your last example i wasn't sure what to put inside of it.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Instead of using Math.floor(float) you can just divide minutesRented/MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR since ints always round down when divided. I will update the code again.

Comment: : error: reached end of file while parsing
            + "Total Cost " + total);
1 error
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)                      I got this error when running that code

Comment: I fixed it i was just missing a curly. thank you so much !!!

Comment: Btw, I'd accept this as the answer so this thread can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using swing, why not create a class which extends JFrame or JPanel and add a JScrollPane or JTextArea. Also add a button  to close the pane as it should in JOptionPane.

Call the class in the main method.  Please note that displahing much information in JOptionPane isn't best practice.

Comment: In all honesty that would probably work very efficiently,  just haven't learned anything about that yet haha.